# How do I flatten dictionary's only deeper than 3 levels

Tags: python, json, nested, flatten

Suppose you have this dictionary

```
{
    "alpha": "one",
    "beta": {
        "beta1": "two",
        "beta2": "second two"
    },
    "gamma": {
        "delta": {
            "delta1": "three",
            "delta2": "second three"
        },
        "epsilon": {
            "zeta": {
                "zeta1": "four",
                "zeta2": "second four"
            },
            "epsilon1": "five",
            "epsilon2": "second five"
        }
    }
}
```

And you want every 3rd (or deeper) nested dictionary to be flattened. So an output like this.

```
{
    "alpha": "one",
    "beta": {
        "beta1": "two",
        "beta2": "second two"
    },
    "gamma": {
        "delta": {
            "delta1": "three",
            "delta2": "second three"
        },
        "epsilon": {
            "zeta.zeta1": "four",
            "zeta.zeta2": "second four",
            "epsilon1": "five",
            "epsilon2": "second five"
        }
    }
}
```

How would one achieve this?

the the tags and structure of the dictionary are dynamic (I want to refactor multiple dictionaries with different structures but a hard line at every third nested dictionary)

I know I can loop through every value, but how would I know when I reached the third nested dictionary?

```
def loopDict(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if type(v) is dict:
            loopDict(v)
        else:
            print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)
```

P.S. I can flatten every dictionary using the `flatten_json` module

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve with this? Usually flattening a structure like this will not improve data handling.

Comment: it will be ugly mess to handle data the way you want from it

Comment: You could add a "level" / "depth" parameter to your ``loopDict`` function and increase it with each recursion, that why you know when you've reached the third level.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to break this one in to two steps.  Loop over the *input_dictionary* to desired target depth.  Then call a flattening function on the innermost dictionaries:

```
def flatten(d):
    for key, value in list(d.items()):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            del d[key]
            for subkey, subvalue in value.items():
                newkey = key + '.' + subkey
                d[newkey] = subvalue

for v1 in input_dict.values():
    if isinstance(v1, dict):
        for v2 in v1.values():
            if isinstance(v2, dict):
                flatten(v2)
```

This outputs:

```
{'alpha': 'one',
 'beta': {'beta1': 'two', 'beta2': 'second two'},
 'gamma': {'delta': {'delta1': 'three', 'delta2': 'second three'},
           'epsilon': {'epsilon1': 'five',
                       'epsilon2': 'second five',
                       'zeta.zeta1': 'four',
                       'zeta.zeta2': 'second four'}}}
```

If something more general is needed, either or both steps can be made recursive.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

For people who look this up I ended up fixing it this way.

`xmldict = {yourdictionary}`

```
for k, v in xmldict.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for ke, va in v.items():
            if isinstance(va, dict):
                for key, val in va.items():
                    if isinstance(val, dict):
                        for key1, val1 in val.items():
                            if isinstance(val1, dict):
                                xmldict[k][ke][key] = flatten(v)
```

You can add or remove for loops depending on depth
(there is prolly a neat-er recursive function that can do this for you)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that, but you were faster! I do, however, share my answer, maybe it can be useful

```py
d = {
    "alpha": "one",
    "beta": {
        "beta1": "two",
        "beta2": "second two"
    },
    "gamma": {
        "delta": {
            "delta1": "three",
            "delta2": "second three"
        },
        "epsilon": {
            "zeta": {
                "zeta1": "four",
                "zeta2": "second four"
            },
            "epsilon1": "five",
            "epsilon2": "second five"
        }
    }
}


def flatten_dict(d):
    def items():
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(value).items():
                    yield key + "." + subkey, subvalue
            else:
                yield key, value

    return dict(items())

def loopDict(d, depth):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if depth > 0:
                d[k] = flatten_dict(v)
            if depth <= 0:
                loopDict(v, depth+1)

    return d

d = loopDict(d, 0)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
data = {'alpha': 'one', 'beta': {'beta1': 'two', 'beta2': 'second two'}, 'gamma': {'delta': {'delta1': 'three', 'delta2': 'second three'}, 'epsilon': {'zeta': {'zeta1': 'four', 'zeta2': 'second four'}, 'epsilon1': 'five', 'epsilon2': 'second five'}}}
def flatten(d, c = [], l = 1):
   for a, b in d.items():
     if not isinstance(b, dict):
       yield a if l < 3 else '.'.join(c+[a]), b
     else:
       if l > 2:
          yield from flatten(b, c=c+[a] if l > 2 else c, l=l+1)
       else:
          yield (a, list(flatten(b, c=c+[a] if l > 2 else c, l=l+1)))

def walk(d):
  return {a:b if not isinstance(b, list) else walk(b) for a, b in d}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(walk(list(flatten(data))), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
  "alpha": "one",
  "beta": {
    "beta1": "two",
    "beta2": "second two"
  },
  "gamma": {
    "delta": {
        "delta1": "three",
        "delta2": "second three"
    },
    "epsilon": {
        "zeta.zeta1": "four",
        "zeta.zeta2": "second four",
        "epsilon1": "five",
        "epsilon2": "second five"
     }
   }
}
```